# PowerShell file paths

Tags: c#, file, powershell, path

I run the command ([Get-Location](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849835.aspx)), and it returns the current location of a file.

Example: `c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\XXX\folder4\folder5`

Firstly, from the above, I want to get the value of XXX and let it equal to a variable. How can I do this?

Secondly, I want to get the value of `c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\XXX\folder4\` and let it equal to a variable. How can I do this?

I have used the placeholders `folder1`, `folder2`, etc. for illustration. These are dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the path into a variable, you can do something like this:

```
$a = (Get-Location).Path
```

Then, if you want to set the value of the 'XXX' part of your path to a variable, you can use the split() function:

```
$x = $a.split('\')[4]
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question first: to get the parent to the full path, use Split-Path:

```
$var = Split-Path -parent "c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\XXX\folder4\folder5"
```

For your other question, this function will split all the elements of your path and return them into an array:

```
function Split-Paths($pth)
{
    while($pth)
    {
        Split-Path -leaf $pth
        $pth = Split-Path -parent $pth
    }
}
```

You can then grab the 5th element like this:

```
$xxx = (Split-Paths "c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\XXX\folder4\folder5")[-5]
```

Note that the function returns the elements in "reverse" order, so you use a negative index to index from the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these answers are pretty close, but everyone is forgetting their shell-fu.

```
$FirstAnswer = (Get-Item ..\..).Name
$SecondAnswer = (Get-Item ..).FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
$rawtext = "If it interests you, my e-mail address is tobias@powershell.com."

# Simple pattern recognition:
$rawtext -match "your regular expression"
  *True*

# Reading data matching the pattern from raw text:
$matches
```

`$matches` returns the result.

For more information, check *[Chapter 13. Text and Regular Expressions](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/archive/2009/03/30/chapter-13-text-and-regular-expressions.aspx)* (requires registration).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a regular expression:

```
PS> $path = 'c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\XXX\folder4\folder5'
PS> $path -match 'c:\\([^\\]+)\\([^\\]+)\\([^\\]+)\\([^\\]+)'
True
PS> $matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
4                              XXX
3                              folder3
2                              folder2
1                              folder1
0                              c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\XXX
```